# C++ when compiler do Template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

As we know in the compilation stage, the compiler will instantiate a concrete type for a template, for example:

```
template<class T> void test(T m )
{
    cout << m << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int kl = 0;
    test<int>(kl);
}
```

In the `main` function, the compiler will try to have a `int` entry. 
Also we know that in the compilation stage, generally we have several steps:
lexical analysis, syntax analysis, grammer analysis and intermediate language(IR).

So my question is: **In which step is the instantiation done? Before IR or after IR?**

Comment: Do not use the [ir] tag. It says so in the tag wiki.

Comment: What is IR? That's highly implementation dependent

Comment: IR means intermediate language which is independent of machine.

Comment: @dyp I removed the tag for you.

Comment: @djechlin Thanks, I guess ;) sehe tried replaced it, but we don't know what to replace it with. My comment was more of a remark to the OP to replace it with something more specific, see sehe's comment.